# How to get an Specific ID from Drive using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to take an specific ID from some folder in my Drive,

```
function listData() {
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('1RHN0lGqJmMtH40IExzI2Tcdftjkp4oUQ');
var list = [];
list.push(['FILENAME','UniqueID']);
var files = fldr.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()){
  file =files.next();
  var row = []
  row.push(file.getName(),file.getId())    
  idFile = file.getId();
  nameFile = file.getName();
  Logger.log(idFile);
}
```

is it possible to get some file ID which is there's was more than 1 file on my drive folder?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do: each file in Google Drive has a unique Id and this is what yo get when calling `file.getId()` so what is the ID you're looking for ?

Comment: i am looking for only one specific file ID of all the files that are in my folder, if i do `file.getId()` it brings up all the file IDs that are in that folder

Comment: if you know the ID in advance, you don't need to go through all the files. What do you want to do with this ID ? And `getId()` by itself simply returns the ID of the current file, it's because you do a while loop that you retrieve all the IDs

Comment: What do you know in advance about the file if not the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will give you the path for a given id

```
function getPathAllDrivesFromId(fileid) {
  var ids = [{id:fileid,name:DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getName()}];
  let r;
  do {
    r = Drive.Files.get(fileid,{supportsAllDrives:true,supportsTeamDrives:true});
    if(r.parents.length > 0) {
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r.parents[0]));
      ids.push({id:r.parents[0].id,name:DriveApp.getFolderById(r.parents[0].id).getName()});
      fileid = r.parents[0].id
    }
  }while (r.parents.length > 0);
  if(ids[ids.length - 1].name == "Drive") {
    ids[ids.length - 1].name = Drive.Drives.get(ids[ids.length - 1].id).name;
  }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  let path = ids.map(obj => obj.name).flat().reverse().join(' / ')
  //Logger.log(path);
  return path;
}
```